# Backbone, trigger an events when all is loaded

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

In my backbone app I load 3 Collections and I bind the "reset" event at the render function. So, in this way, when I fetch the Collections, I print the various results, but not simultaneously.

I would use the jquery deferred methods ($.when, $.then) to print all simultaneously, how to do this if I use the "bind events" on the views?

this is the code:

Router:

```
App.Routers.test1 = Backbone.Router.extend({  

    routes: {       
        "/test" : "test"        
    },

    initialize: function() {                            
        // Models
        this.Models_1 =     new App.Collections.coll_1;     
        this.Models_2 =     new App.Collections.coll_2;
        this.Models_3 =     new App.Collections.coll_3;

        // Views
        this.View_1 =       new App.Views.view_1( {model: this.Models_1} );
        this.View_2 =       new App.Views.view_2( {model: this.Models_2} );
        this.View_3 =       new App.Views.view_3( {model: this.Models_3} );         
    },

    test: function() { 
        $.when(

            this.Models_1.fetch(),
            this.Models_2.fetch(),
            this.Models_3.fetch()

        ).then(function() {

            // ?????????????????????????

            //  What should I do here?

            // ?????????????????????????

        });
    }

});
```

View 1:

```
App.Views.view_1 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {

        // print the data...

    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test: function() { 
    $.when(
        this.Models_1.fetch({silent: YES}), // silent will prevent triggering any events on reset or add
        this.Models_2.fetch({silent: YES}),
        this.Models_3.fetch({silent: YES})
    ).then(_.bind(function() {
        this.Models_1.trigger('reset'); // manually trigger events in sequence you want
        this.Models_3.trigger('reset');
        this.Models_2.trigger('reset');
    }, this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are going with your deferred events. Backbone already has a way to do this.

In your view, bind the event "refresh" from the collection to the view render function. Whenever you will call fetch on the collection, the refresh event will be triggered and your view rerendered.

Comment: With the last version of backbone the event "refresh" is been replaced with "reset". However now the application is functioning normally, but I would that when I call the fetch on the collection, the app wait that all collections are been loaded, and then proceed with the rendering. In this way the views will print simultaneously.

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear from your question. I guess you should remove the binding to the reset event and create a new "loading:done" or something like that. Listen for it in your views and trigger it in you "then".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps underscores [defer](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#defer) is the method you're looking for?

> Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared, similar to using setTimeout with a delay of 0. Useful for performing expensive computations or HTML rendering in chunks without blocking the UI thread from updating.