# How to trigger an Event after rendering Views with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have many Views whos work with templates. The Rendering with the Views work perfectly, now into my Router i'm seeking to a way to trigger an Event when all Views rendered!
 I used js loader like LAB.js but nothing work!

After all rendered i enter the event into the firebug console and it's work!

How and Here can i place my event so that it's trigger when all views rendered!

**My Event : **

```
$('div[id ^="solfg_"]').mobilyblocks();
```

**Router : **

```
(function () {

 window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes: {
  ""  : "init"
 },

 init: function(){

   this.solfsmodel = new Solfs();
   this.solfsmodel.fetch(); 
   this.solfsView = new SolfsView({model: this.solfsmodel});

 }

});
var app_router = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
}(jQuery));
```

Thank you

**update :** [same problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7150533/649605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution just use $.when().then() from jquery, really amazing that i never saw this jquery function.

**My Solution : **

```
(function () {

 window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes: {
   ""  : "run"
 },

initialize: function(){
  this.solfsmodel = new Solfs();

  this.solfsView = new SolfsView({model: this.solfsmodel});

},
run: function(){
  $.when(
     this.solfsmodel.fetch(); 
  ).then(function(){
     *$('div[id ^="solfg_"]').mobilyblocks();*
  });
}
});
var app_router = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Have you bind your collection to the view ? Because if you just need to wait that the collection is fetched, you can use the event `success` or `error`. I'll write a new answer to show you how do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `success` callback of `fetch` method if you just need to wait that the collection is fetched (source: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

It's preferable to use Backbone.js method before use other librairies.

So your code should look like:

```
(function () {

    window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ""  : "run"
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.solfsmodel = new Solfs();
            this.solfsView = new SolfsView({model: this.solfsmodel});
        },

        run: function(){
            this.solfsmodel.fetch({
                success: function () { 
                    $('div[id ^="solfg_"]').mobilyblocks();
                }
            );
        }
    });
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: And how do u do if you have more than one model? do you implement for each fetch a Success?

Comment: Indeed if you give more than one model, $.when is a better solution. But don't forget to check if an error occurred or not.